# Signal another thread within the same process

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, signals

I have an application which processes certain data, and displays that in a UI.

Initially I had just a single thread, the main process, doing the work, i.e., retrieving the data for processing, processing the data, and then updating the UI. The data resides on another server.

However, the requirements for the application changed, and much more data has to be retrieved from the server and processed than previously thought. This is creating performance issues, since data has to retrieved, processed and then the UI has to figure out where it should be put

The UI is `CListCtrl` based MFC controls.

To combat this, I have split the processing n two threads, one which acquired the data and processes it, and another which will display it, i.e. the GUI.

I need some way to signal the `UI` thread, that the data has been fetched and processed. The thread is created using `CreateThread`. What is the best way to signal the other thread that it can do its own job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following: when your separate thread has to notify the GUI something you should call a PostMessage to the window containing the controls.

The message param should be a user defined message so something defined by you e.g.

```
#define WM_MYMESSAGE (WM_USER + 1)
```

The other two params (LPARAM and LPARAM) will contain data you need to pass to the GUI. So in CreateThread you need to pass some info about the window that will receive the message (the CWnd pointer if you use MFC, HWND handle otherwise).

Then you need to handle this message inside you window (see references about ON_COMMAND and the like macros)

Comment: OK - So at the place where I need the send the notification, I have  done a `PostMessage(this->GetSafeHwnd(), WM_COMPLETE, 0, 0)'  . Also, I have defined a  'ON_MESSAGE(WM_COMPLETE, &someClass::someFunc())`, where `someFunc()` is `LRESULT someFunc(WPARAM, LPARAM)`. And I execute the application, but somehow, despite putting the `breakpoint`, it does not seem to hit the function. I have a feeling the Handle of the window is the issue, but it is a CDialog derived class, and I am getting the Handle using getSafeHwnd() in InitDoalog() before the processing thread is created.WHat could be the issue

Comment: Except, `WM_USER+x` is not meant for application use. This range of messages is for use by window implementations. Use `WM_APP+x` instead.

Comment: @user: As it turns out, for a dialog `WM_USER+1` is in fact `DM_SETDEFID`, a message that is already attached to a message handler. As pointed out in my previous comment, marom has picked the wrong ranges of messages. Use `WM_APP+1` instead.